# How to make checkbox without a background programmatically?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, null

I'm new to Android development and I'd like help from the experts here.
I make my `checkbox` change its background color to red upon a specific condition, and then I need to return its background color to the original one. I've tried the following code, but it gives me an error, so I'd like to know the correct code for doing so?
I have tried various ways, but nothing helps me solve my problem.

```
 Female.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("@null"));
 Male.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("@null"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the color to transparent what is the same as setting the background to `@null`:

```
Female.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
Male.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Can be simplified by using just `0` but I think it is easier to understand if there is the ARGB code.